# Create a resizable view in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am creating a resizable view for an image. The code is as follows:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: SafeArea(
          child: ImageManager(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

final ballRadius = 7.5;

class ImageManager extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ImageManagerState createState() => _ImageManagerState();
}

class _ImageManagerState extends State<ImageManager> {
  double _x = 0;
  double _y = 0;

  double _height = 200;
  double _width = 300;

  double _aspectRatio = 200 / 300;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      overflow: Overflow.visible,
      children: <Widget>[
        Positioned(
          top: _y,
          left: _x,
          child: GestureDetector(
            onPanUpdate: (DragUpdateDetails details) {
              setState(() {
                _x += details.delta.dx;
                _y += details.delta.dy;
              });
            },
            child: Image.network(
              "https://via.placeholder.com/300x200",
              width: _width,
            ),
          ),
        ),

        // top left
        Positioned(
          top: _y - ballRadius,
          left: _x - ballRadius,
          child: Ball(
            onDragStart: () {},
            onDrag: (double dx, double dy) {},
            onDragEnd: () {},
          ),
        ),

        // top middle
        Positioned(
          top: _y - ballRadius,
          left: _x + _width / 2 - ballRadius,
          child: Ball(
            onDragStart: () {},
            onDrag: (double dx, double dy) {},
            onDragEnd: () {},
          ),
        ),

        // top right
        Positioned(
          top: _y - ballRadius,
          left: _x + _width - ballRadius,
          child: Ball(
            onDragStart: () {},
            onDrag: (double dx, double dy) {},
            onDragEnd: () {},
          ),
        ),

        // middle left
        Positioned(
          top: _y + _height / 2 - ballRadius,
          left: _x - ballRadius,
          child: Ball(
            onDragStart: () {},
            onDrag: (double dx, double dy) {},
            onDragEnd: () {},
          ),
        ),

        // middle right
        Positioned(
          top: _y + _height / 2 - ballRadius,
          left: _x + _width - ballRadius,
          child: Ball(
            onDragStart: () {},
            onDrag: (double dx, double dy) {},
            onDragEnd: () {},
          ),
        ),

        // bottom left
        Positioned(
          top: _y + _height - ballRadius,
          left: _x - ballRadius,
          child: Ball(
            onDragStart: () {},
            onDrag: (double dx, double dy) {},
            onDragEnd: () {},
          ),
        ),

        // bottom middle
        Positioned(
          top: _y + _height - ballRadius,
          left: _x + _width / 2 - ballRadius,
          child: Ball(
            onDragStart: () {},
            onDrag: (double dx, double dy) {},
            onDragEnd: () {},
          ),
        ),

        // bottom right
        Positioned(
          top: _y + _height - ballRadius,
          left: _x + _width - ballRadius,
          child: Ball(
            onDragStart: () {},
            onDrag: (double dx, double dy) {
              var mid = (dx + dy) / 2;
              var newWidth = _width + 2 * mid;
              var newHeight = newWidth * _aspectRatio;

              setState(() {
                _width = newWidth;
                _height = newHeight;
                _y = _y - dy;
                _x = _x - 2 * dx;
              });
            },
            onDragEnd: () {},
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}

class Ball extends StatelessWidget {
  final Function onDragStart;
  final Function onDrag;
  final Function onDragEnd;

  const Ball({this.onDragStart, this.onDrag, this.onDragEnd});

  void _onDragStart(DragStartDetails details) {
    if (onDragStart != null) onDragStart();
  }

  void _onDragUpdate(DragUpdateDetails details) {
    if (onDrag != null) onDrag(details.delta.dx, details.delta.dy);
  }

  void _onDragEnd(DragEndDetails details) {
    if (onDragEnd != null) onDragEnd();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onPanStart: _onDragStart,
      onPanUpdate: _onDragUpdate,
      onPanEnd: _onDragEnd,
      child: Container(
        height: 2 * ballRadius,
        width: 2 * ballRadius,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.blue,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(ballRadius),
          border: Border.all(
            width: 3,
            color: Colors.white,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

My goal is to uniformly resize like the following:

[image]

However, currently, it looks like this.

[image]

As you can see that the x and y coordinates are messed up. The goal here is if you resize the image from the bottom right corner then the image will stay at the top left corner. Please help with this. Thanks.

Comment: do you want drag functionality too ? ... or you want just resize functionality ?

Comment: @mohandesR Currently, I need both drag and resize.

Comment: please look at this... i tried to make what you want ...
https://dartpad.dev/44adae92cecbd2dddc00f264293e5c3a

Comment: @mohandesR Thank you so much for the code. If it's not too much to ask, can you help me with top left handle as well?

Comment: YES ...Of Course

Comment: @Sajjad Can you help me with all other position ball like top middle, bottom middle and all i am stuck here

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i change the the top left positioned like this

```
 // top left
    Positioned(
      top: _y - ballRadius,
      left: _x - ballRadius,
      child: Ball(
        onDragStart: () {},
        onDrag: (double dx, double dy) {
          var newWidth = _width - dx;
          var newHeight = newWidth * _aspectRatio;
          setState(() {
            _y = _y + (_height - newHeight);
            _x = _x + dx;
            _width = newWidth ;
            _height = newHeight;
          });
        },
        onDragEnd: () {},
      ),
    ),
```

and bottom right positioned (just for completing Answer)

```
        Positioned(
      top: _y + _height - ballRadius,
      left: _x + _width - ballRadius,
      child: Ball(
        onDragStart: () {},
        onDrag: (double dx, double dy) {

          var newWidth = _width + dx;
          var newHeight = newWidth * _aspectRatio;

          setState(() {
            _width = newWidth ;
            _height = newHeight;
          });
        },
        onDragEnd: () {},
      ),
    ),
```

and adding this parameter to image.network

```
fit: BoxFit.fill,
```

full code at here :
https://dartpad.dev/44adae92cecbd2dddc00f264293e5c3a

Comment: Hi, @Sajjad can you do the bottom left and top right as well?

Comment: @AgentRed its same of top left and you need to play with parameters to create new values of flowing `newWidth` and `newHeight` and  `_y ` and `_x`,

Comment: that's what I'm doing but I cannot find the correct formula, please help me.

Comment: @Sajjad It would be great if you can do it for bottom left and top right

Comment: @KalpeshKhandla sure, I am going to update the answer as soon as possible.

Comment: @Sajjad Thanks for your response & support. I have already done it.

Comment: Can someone who did the other two corners show how they did it?

Answer (score 1):

```
  Complete code will look like a below.

  import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
  import 'package:flutter_text_to_image/utils/app_colors.dart';
  import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
  import 'package:flutter_text_to_image/utils/app_string.dart';
  import 'package:flutter_text_to_image/widgets/draggable_text_form_field_widget.dart';
  
 /*
  Title: DraggableTextFormFieldScreen
  Purpose: DraggableTextFormFieldScreen
  Created On : 16/11/2022
  Last Updated On : 16/11/2022
  Author : Kalpesh Khandla
  */

  class DraggableTextFormFieldScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State
  <DraggableTextFormFieldScreen>
  createState() =>
  _DraggableTextFormFieldScreenState();
  }
  class _DraggableTextFormFieldScreenState
  extends State
  <DraggableTextFormFieldScreen>
  {
  TextEditingController wordController = TextEditingController();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
  body: SafeArea(
  child: DraggableWidget(),
  ),
  );
  }
  }
  class DraggableWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _DraggableWidgetState createState() => _DraggableWidgetState();
  }
  TextEditingController wordController = TextEditingController();
  const ballDiameter = 7.5;
  class _DraggableWidgetState extends State
  <DraggableWidget>
  {
  double height = 70;
  double width = 250;
  double topPosition = 250;
  double leftPosition = 70;
  void onDrag(double dx, double dy) {
  var newHeight = height + dy;
  var newWidth = width + dx;
  setState(() {
  height = newHeight > 0 ? newHeight : 0;
  width = newWidth > 0 ? newWidth : 0;
  });
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
  resizeToAvoidBottomInset: true,
  body: SafeArea(
  child: GestureDetector(
  onPanUpdate: (details) {
  setState(() {
  topPosition += details.delta.dy;
  leftPosition += details.delta.dx;
  });
  },
  child: Stack(
  children: 
  <Widget>
  [
  Positioned(
  top: topPosition,
  left: leftPosition,
  child: Container(
  height: height,
  width: width,
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
  color: AppColors.whiteColor,
  border: Border.all(
  color: AppColors.textfieldBorderColor.withOpacity(0.7),
  ),
  ),
  child: Center(
  child: DraggableTextFormFieldWidget(
  controllerName: wordController,
  hintTxt: AppStrings.textfieldHintTxt,
  keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
  cursorColor: AppColors.textfieldBorderColor,
  contentPadding: 25,
  onChange: (p0) {},
  onSaved: (p0) {},
  validatorData: (p0) {},
  ),
  ),
  ),
  ),
  // top left
  Positioned(
  top: topPosition - ballDiameter / 2,
  left: leftPosition - ballDiameter / 2,
  child: SelectorWidget(
  onDrag: (dx, dy) {
  var mid = (dx + dy) / 2;
  var newHeight = height - 2 * mid;
  var newWidth = width - 2 * mid;
  setState(() {
  height = newHeight > 0 ? newHeight : 0;
  width = newWidth > 0 ? newWidth : 0;
  topPosition = topPosition + mid;
  leftPosition = leftPosition + mid;
  });
  },
  ),
  ),
  // top middle
  Positioned(
  top: topPosition - ballDiameter / 2,
  left: leftPosition + width / 2 - ballDiameter / 2,
  child: SelectorWidget(
  onDrag: (dx, dy) {
  var newHeight = height - dy;
  setState(() {
  height = newHeight > 0 ? newHeight : 0;
  topPosition = topPosition + dy;
  });
  },
  ),
  ),
  // top right
  Positioned(
  top: topPosition - ballDiameter / 2,
  left: leftPosition + width - ballDiameter / 2,
  child: SelectorWidget(
  onDrag: (dx, dy) {
  var mid = (dx + (dy * -1)) / 2;
  var newHeight = height + 2 * mid;
  var newWidth = width + 2 * mid;
  setState(() {
  height = newHeight > 0 ? newHeight : 0;
  width = newWidth > 0 ? newWidth : 0;
  topPosition = topPosition - mid;
  leftPosition = leftPosition - mid;
  });
  },
  ),
  ),
  // center right
  Positioned(
  top: topPosition + height / 2 - ballDiameter / 2,
  left: leftPosition + width - ballDiameter / 2,
  child: SelectorWidget(
  onDrag: (dx, dy) {
  var newWidth = width + dx;
  setState(() {
  width = newWidth > 0 ? newWidth : 0;
  });
  },
  ),
  ),
  // bottom right
  Positioned(
  top: topPosition + height - ballDiameter / 2,
  left: leftPosition + width - ballDiameter / 2,
  child: SelectorWidget(
  onDrag: (dx, dy) {
  var mid = (dx + dy) / 2;
  var newHeight = height + 2 * mid;
  var newWidth = width + 2 * mid;
  setState(() {
  height = newHeight > 0 ? newHeight : 0;
  width = newWidth > 0 ? newWidth : 0;
  topPosition = topPosition - mid;
  leftPosition = leftPosition - mid;
  });
  },
  ),
  ),
  // bottom center
  Positioned(
  top: topPosition + height - ballDiameter / 2,
  left: leftPosition + width / 2 - ballDiameter / 2,
  child: SelectorWidget(
  onDrag: (dx, dy) {
  var newHeight = height + dy;
  setState(() {
  height = newHeight > 0 ? newHeight : 0;
  });
  },
  ),
  ),
  // bottom left
  Positioned(
  top: topPosition + height - ballDiameter / 2,
  left: leftPosition - ballDiameter / 2,
  child: SelectorWidget(
  onDrag: (dx, dy) {
  var mid = ((dx * -1) + dy) / 2;
  var newHeight = height + 2 * mid;
  var newWidth = width + 2 * mid;
  setState(() {
  height = newHeight > 0 ? newHeight : 0;
  width = newWidth > 0 ? newWidth : 0;
  topPosition = topPosition - mid;
  leftPosition = leftPosition - mid;
  });
  },
  ),
  ),
  //left center
  Positioned(
  top: topPosition + height / 2 - ballDiameter / 2,
  left: leftPosition - ballDiameter / 2,
  child: SelectorWidget(
  onDrag: (dx, dy) {
  var newWidth = width - dx;
  setState(() {
  width = newWidth > 0 ? newWidth : 0;
  leftPosition = leftPosition + dx;
  });
  },
  ),
  ),
  //  center center
  ],
  ),
  ),
  ),
  );
  }
  }
  class SelectorWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  SelectorWidget({
  required this.onDrag,
  });
  final Function onDrag;
  @override
  _SelectorWidgetState createState() => _SelectorWidgetState();
  }
  class _SelectorWidgetState extends State
  <SelectorWidget>
  {
  late double initX;
  late double initY;
  _handleDrag(details) {
  setState(() {
  initX = details.globalPosition.dx;
  initY = details.globalPosition.dy;
  });
  }
  _handleUpdate(details) {
  var dx = details.globalPosition.dx - initX;
  var dy = details.globalPosition.dy - initY;
  initX = details.globalPosition.dx;
  initY = details.globalPosition.dy;
  widget.onDrag(dx, dy);
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return GestureDetector(
  onPanStart: _handleDrag,
  onPanUpdate: _handleUpdate,
  child: Container(
  height: 10,
  width: 10,
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(2),
  color: AppColors.whiteColor,
  border: Border.all(
  width: 1.5,
  color: AppColors.textfieldBorderColor.withOpacity(0.9),
  ),
  ),
  ),
  );
  }
  @override
  void debugFillProperties(DiagnosticPropertiesBuilder properties) {
  super.debugFillProperties(properties);
  properties.add(DoubleProperty('X Cordinates', initX));
  }
  }
```

Comment: Do not forget to upvote if it helpful

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at a brand new widget implemented in Flutter 1.20, `InteractiveViewer`. It allows you to zoom and pan a child.

You could also use a combination of `GestureDetector` and `StatefulBuilder` to update a child every time you drag your finger