# flutter sizing and rotating a widget with gestures

Tags: flutter

I am trying to implement resizing and rotation capabilities to a container with some text in it.

It's pretty basic. I want to rotate it if the user taps with two fingers and rotates. I want to resize it if the user taps with two fingers and move them away or closer.

I was able to find some partially related questions/guides but for a total beginner to these gestures, what should I do, is there a good resource I can check out?

Comment: this is not Exactly what you want ... but can help you for get an Idea .https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63951617/create-a-resizable-view-in-flutter/63954279#63954279

Comment: I think this is can help ... https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/InteractiveViewer-class.html

Comment: @mohandesR yes I found it too but there seems to be a lot of bugs that hasn't been fixed yet. I think they closed the issues on github but I get the same errors people got when it was first released. i.e. a lot of the time it doesn't pick up movements.