# How to make draggable circle google map in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation, flutter-test

I am trying to make draggable circle in google maps in flutter but i don't know how to do that?
How can i do it in flutter?
I have the circle on google map
widget but i can't drag it

```
Set<Circle> circles = Set.from([Circle(
    circleId: CircleId(id),
    center: LatLng(latitude, longitude),
    radius: 4000,
)]);

GoogleMap(
    mapType: MapType.normal,
    myLocationEnabled: true,
    myLocationButtonEnabled: true,
    initialCameraPosition: initialMapLocation,
    onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller) {
      _controller.complete(controller);
    },
    onCameraMove: null,
    circles: circles,
  );
```

Answer (score -1):

please look at this Question and answer . for Drag and Resize a View

https://stackoverflow.com/a/63954279/6813907

Comment: it didn't work with me because it isn't widget. that was my error : The argument type 'Circle' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Widget'

Comment: may be its possible to add the map in a stack and add custom circles on It .